# How can i quickly search a specific id and get all rows of that id in a large database in Laravel with mysql?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am making a result publishing system application in Laravel . I am importing Large number results (like 1000000) of students in MYSQL database. the student can search there result by role number and registration number. 
i will give two input and the whole result database needed to be search and find the result of the student .How i should i approach to searching the result so that the search result is found very quickly. thanks

Comment: do you need to modify the data before serving it?

Comment: @aaron0207  no , just search

Comment: If there are correct indexes it would be fast just paginate the results

Comment: @aaron0207  i will give two input and the whole result database needed to be search and find the result of the student

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <formclass="forminline" action="{{URL::to('searchEmployie')}}" method="get"> 
        <div class="form-group">  
            <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="{{ trans('app.search_for_action')}}" value="{{Request::get('search')}}"> 
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline btn-default"><i class="icon fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

            @if (Request::get('search') != '')
                <a href="{{URL::to('employie')}}" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger" type="button"><i class="icon fa-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            @endif
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

`controller`

```
$q = Input::get('search');
$employie = Employie::where('employee_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')->paginate(2);
```